# My code return cannot implicitly convert int to bool

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm new here, excuse me if I wasn't comprehensible. I'm setting up a new class for my `div`, using conditional operator `?:`, after the `:` I'm getting the error

```
CssClass = 
(idee.IdTypeEtatIdee == (int)EnumTypeEtatIdee.example? "example" : 
((int)EnumTypeEtatIdee.exampletwo ? "Aletude" :
((int)EnumTypeEtatIdee.examplethree? "Encours" :
((int)EnumTypeEtatIdee.examplefour ? "examplefour " : 
((int)EnumTypeEtatIdee.examplefive ? "examplefive " : "null"))))),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't test multiple values this way, you have to specify the test value each time:

```
CssClass = 
(idee.IdTypeEtatIdee == (int)EnumTypeEtatIdee.example? "example" : 
(idee.IdTypeEtatIdee == (int)EnumTypeEtatIdee.exampletwo ? "Aletude" :
(idee.IdTypeEtatIdee == (int)EnumTypeEtatIdee.examplethree? "Encours" :
(idee.IdTypeEtatIdee == (int)EnumTypeEtatIdee.examplefour ? "examplefour " : 
(idee.IdTypeEtatIdee == (int)EnumTypeEtatIdee.examplefive ? "examplefive " : "null")))))
```

You could instead use a `switch` to accomplish the same thing

```
var CssClass = "null";
switch((EnumTypeEtatIdee)idee.IdTypeEtatIdee){
    case EnumTypeEtatIdee.example:
        CssClass = "example";
        break;
    case EnumTypeEtatIdee.exampletwo:
        CssClass = "Aletude";
        break;
    case EnumTypeEtatIdee.examplethree:
        CssClass = "Encours";
        break;
    case EnumTypeEtatIdee.examplefour:
        CssClass = "examplefour";
        break;
    case EnumTypeEtatIdee.examplefive:
        CssClass = "examplefive";
        break;
}
```

Or a dictionary:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<EnumTypeEtatIdee, string>(){
    {EnumTypeEtatIdee.example, "example"},
    {EnumTypeEtatIdee.exampletwo, "Aletude"},
    {EnumTypeEtatIdee.examplethree, "Encours"},
    {EnumTypeEtatIdee.examplefour, "examplefour"},
    {EnumTypeEtatIdee.examplefive, "examplefive"},
};

var CssClass = "null";
if (myDict.ContainsKey((EnumTypeEtatIdee)idee.IdTypeEtatIdee)){
    CssClass = myDict[(EnumTypeEtatIdee)idee.IdTypeEtatIdee];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use ternary oprator `?` which is used like this (pseudo code):

```
BOOLEAN expression ? value if true : value if false;
```

First argument is `BOOLEAN expression`, which should be `bool` itself, or expression evaluating to `bool`, for instance:

```
(int)EnumTypeEtatIdee.example == 2019 ? ...
```

Now you are trying to pass `int` there, which will result in error.

Check this for reference: [?: operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)